# How can I use a TP Link USB wireless adapter without having to reinstall the driver every time?

Tags: drivers, wireless, atheros

I'm new to Ubuntu 11.10. I've followed [some guides](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Device/TP-Link_TL-WN620G_%28ndiswrapper) on how to install USB wifi drivers, but every time I boot up my system my wifi adapter is not working.

In order for it to work I have to

- remove my usb wireless adapter
- remove the installed driver
- reinstall the driver before plugging the usb wireless adapter

If i install the driver while the device is plugged nothing will happen.

I want ubuntu to detect my USB wireless adapter every time I boot/reboot my PC. Doing the procedure (mentioned above) every time I boot/reboot my PC is a chore.

I'm using a desktop PC and using a tp-link usb wireless adapter via AR5523 driver.

Here's an update: it's really weird but by accident I forgot to remove my usb while doing the re-installation of the driver. The driver detected my USB wifi adapter and all of a sudden my adapter's light indicator starts flashing (unlike before my adapter will not function).

Comment: Can you add a link to the guides you followed? It's impossible to answer this question without knowing how you're loading the driver.

Comment: hi.. here's just one of the the link:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Device/TP-Link_TL-WN620G_(ndiswrapper) i can't recall the other links i've been through. From here i used the windows wireless drivers application to do the process that i've mentioned above...

Comment: ok here's an update: it's really weird but by accident i forgot to remove my usb while doing the re-installation of the driver. the driver detected my usb wifi adapter and all of a sudden my adapter's light indicator starts flashing(unlike before my adapter will not function). i'm sorry for the redundancy(if any) of this topic. still hoping that someone will be able to help me with my problem.

Answer (score 2):

OP found solution:

Ok here's an update: it's really weird but by accident I forgot to remove my usb while doing the re-installation of the driver. The driver detected my usb wifi adapter and all of a sudden my adapter's light indicator starts flashing(unlike before my adapter will not function). I'm sorry for the redundancy(if any) of this topic. Still hoping that someone will be able to help me with my problem

Answer (score 0):

I have XUbuntu 11.10 amd64 and a Bandridge CNW4102 USB Wifi adapter.
This solution is based on h_t_t_p_:_//forum.ubuntu-it.org/index.php/topic,391516.0.html and it works for me (but I suppose it will work with most AR5523 based adapters).

1. Determine that you need AR5523 firmware:

   ```
   ~$ sudo lsusb
   ```

   *Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0d8e:7801 Global Sun Technology, Inc. AR5523*

   Before succeeding, after AR5523 it said "(no firmware loaded)"... so here we go:
2. Get the AR5523 firmware souces from SVN and unpack them

   `svn co svn://svn.berlios.de/fullstory/ar5523/trunk/ ar5523`
   `wget http://verein.lst.de/~hch/ar5523.tgz`
   `tar xf ar5523.tgz ar5523/uath-ar5523.bin --strip 1`
3. Build the *deb package for your adapter.
   In the aforementioned tutorial, the next command didn't have the -d switch and resulted in a failure due an unsatisfied dependency "Unmet build dependencies: debhelper (>= 9.20120115)"

   I've used  the -d switch because I've had debhelper installed already and the only shortcoming was the version.

   `cd ar5523 && dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -d`
4. Install the package

   `sudo dpkg -i ../ar5523-source*deb`
5. Build and install an ar5523-modules-* package for your system, using Module-Assistant.

   `sudo m-a a-i ar5523`
6. Install the device firmware.

   `sudo mkdir /usr/local/lib/firmware`
   `sudo mv ../uath-ar5523.bin /usr/local/lib/firmware`
7. Load the ar5523 module.

   `sudo modprobe ar5523`
   `modprobe -l |grep ar5523
   *misc/ar5523.ko*`
8. Verify your device has an available interface.

   `sudo iwconfig`

   `*lo        no wireless extensions.`
    `eth1      no wireless extensions.`
    `wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any`
   `Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm`
   `Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off`
   `Encryption key:off`
   `Power Management:off*`
9. Now you can use your WiFi adapter (configure it via *ifconfig, Network-Manager* etc.)

I hope that was useful (you'll find this on my blog at h_t_t_p_:_//razvandudu.blogspot.com/2012/04/adaptor-wifi-cu-ar5523-xubuntu-1110.html).